# Escaping $ interpolation in heredoc

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the heredoc:

```
user_data = <<-USERDATA

#!/bin/bash
echo "server {" >> /etc/nginx/sites-available/site
echo "    listen 80;" >> /etc/nginx/sites-available/site
echo "    location / {" >> /etc/nginx/sites-available/site
echo "        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;" >> /etc/nginx/sites-available/site
echo "        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;" >> /etc/nginx/sites-available/site
echo "    }" >> /etc/nginx/sites-available/site
echo "}" >> /etc/nginx/sites-available/site

-USERDATA
```

Now, `$remote_addr;` and `$http_host;` should not be interpolated, but is, and is empty when I get the output.

I've tried using `$$remote_addr`; but that also returns an empty result, instead of the string `$remote_addr;`

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong with regards to escaping the $ character ?

**Workaround**

By using terraforms interpolation, I was able to render the string, `${"$remote_addr;"}` which returns $remote_addr;

But perhaps a nicer solution exists ?

Comment: The escape character is backslash... `\$remote_addr`.

Comment: [Or turn off all expansions by quoting the delimiter part of `<<-BLAH` (or any character(s) of it)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents) PS: you don't appear to have any leading tabs so you don't actually need the `-` and _shouldn't_ have it on the actual delimiter (at the end)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use delimiters to insert chunks of text into file, making it perhaps a bit easier to read e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOM >/etc/nginx/sites-available/site
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For \$remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host \$http_host;
    }
}
EOM
```

but you'd still need to escape $ signs as suggested in comments (\$).